# Does TextBox.Clear()'s performance degrade over time?

Tags: .net, wpf, performance

I have an application that after about an hour of use it starts to slow down.  Over the course of the last week I have checked for memory leaks and other similar "time based" problems.

I finally wired up the new TimeLine Trace form the dotTrace profiler.  It showed me that the most of the time was in `TextBox.Clear()` method (about 3 seconds of my total 5 second delay).

I did some reading and found this [post](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Microsoft_Development/A_10775-WPF-TextBox-Text-String-Empty-vs-TextBox-Clear-vs-TextBox-ClearValue-vs-TextBox-SetValue.html) saying that `TextBox.Clear()` is 42 times slower than setting the TextBox value to an empty string.

**But this does not answer why my app only slows down after an hour of use.**

I looked at the `TextBox.Clear()` method, and it seems to be treating the content more like a Edit Box (with sections of text).

Could repeated calls to Clear be creating a growing list of object on the text box?

**Or does anyone else have an Idea why this would slow down over an hour of repeated calls to `TextBox.Clear()`?**

**UPDATE:**
I just found this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8108dd89-7d2a-4e23-abaf-fd1a33807ed9/textboxclear-seems-to-leak-some-memory-outofmemoryexception?forum=wpf) that seems to indicate that a textbox has an undo stack that has no limit.  Maybe my calls to clear are making adding values to that stack slower over time.

**UPDATE 2:**
I make a little test app that will clear a textbox 1500 times when a button is pressed.  I pressed it about 30 times.  About 70% of the it took around 45 ms.  But the other 30% it took beteen 1.8 and 5.4 SECONDS!

I have no idea why it would have such a dramatic shift in time.  Still, my app maybe has 2000 clear calls for the whole hour, so that does not seem like it is proof as to why the Profiler says that `TextBox.Clear()` is the problem.

Comment: Is that stack for all controls or each control has its own stack?

Comment: So did you try playing around with the undo limit on that control?

Comment: @SharpCode - There are two stacks that that each iterate through 3 controls.  So each control is cleared twice.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - The problem only happens after an hour.  And we have not been able to reproduce it in our development environment.   But I plan to change those values to try it out.  But a release to production takes time.  So I would like to have proof that I am heading in the write direction.

Comment: Why are you not binding?

Comment: @Blam - I am binding, via a behavior.  (I have looked at the behavior to see if it is causing the problem and I don't see anything there).

Comment: Why don't you just try replacing the calls to `TextBox.Clear` with calls to set the data bound value to an empty `string` and see if that makes a difference?

Comment: If you are binding then why are you calling TextBox.Clear()?  Why cause extra traffic?

Comment: @Sheridan - we are trying something like that today.

Comment: @Blam - It is complicated.  We have a behavior on the textbox that requires the user to enter the text twice.  (To ensure accuracy.)  I checked that behavior and it seems clean, but it is because of the behavior that we call clear, instead of just blanking the bound value.

Answer (score 0):

I do know know why for sure, but changing to `TextBox.Text = String.Empty;` fixed my performance problems.

I went back to my release branch and changed ONLY that and now my app runs for hours with no slow downs.

NOTE: I do not think it was the Undo Stack.  I checked the default value that my app had (running under .NET 4.5) and it was limited to 100 (or 10, I can't recall).  Either way, the computers that were going slow did not show any memory pressure.

If I had to guess, I would say that Clear has blocking stuff in it.  The profiler showed some fairly low level calls going on inside the Clear method.  I think one of those were blocking somehow.